# Using sed to replace between a specific pattern

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, string

I've been trying with `sed`, and googling for the whole morning, and I can't seem to get this to work.

Is it possible with `sed` to **lowercase** text between two specific characters:

i.e.

```
SOMENAME=WOODSTOCK,
SOMEOTHERNAME=JIMMY,
```

can I **lowercase** **`WOODSTOCK`** and **`JIMMY`** (to woodstock and jimmy) on the basis they are between `=` and `,`?

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`, or is `awk` e.g. also a possibility? Also, please explain whether the entire file you are trying to modify consists of lines as you show in the example, or if there are other text structures that may need special consideration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible with GNU sed. Choose one of these two forms based on the greediness of the replacement.

```
sed 's|=.*,|\L&|' file
sed 's|=[^,]*,|\L&|' file
```

[As the manual states](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html), "`\L` turns the replacement to lowercase until a `\U` or `\E` is found". `&` is the text matched by the regex.

---

I have modified the sample file to show that you should wisely choose between the geedy `=.*,` and the non-greedy `=[^,]*,` regexes:

```
$ cat file
SOMENAME=WOODSTOCK,
SOMEOTHERNAME2=JIMMY,WOODSTOCK,FINISH
$ sed 's|=.*,|\L&|' file
SOMENAME=woodstock,
SOMEOTHERNAME2=jimmy,woodstock,FINISH
$ sed 's|=[^,]*,|\L&|' file
SOMENAME=woodstock,
SOMEOTHERNAME2=jimmy,WOODSTOCK,FINISH
```

Comment: this is awesome and exactly what I needed. thank you. I'm a dev, (as you can see on my SO profile) but I struggle with sed, any good resources to learn it you can recommend? thanks again.

Comment: @Woodstock You're welcome! I learned it mainly by [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html). The [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) also seems pretty nice to learn, although I have only used it as a reference.

Comment: thanks a lot, super helpful!

Answer (score 4):

On any POSIX compliant `awk`, you can use the `tolower()` function

```
awk -v FS='=' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { $2 = tolower($2) }1 ' file
```

Use the `mktemp()` function to create a temp file to redirect the output of above command and then re-direct back to save in-place. Or use GNU `awk` >= 4.1 with `-i inplace`

Another variant of POSIX compliant version, using `match()` function would be to do

```
awk 'match($0, /=([^,]*),/) { str = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2); sub(str, tolower(str)) }1'
```

Comment: The problem is that I suspect the sample input given by the OP may not be a complete representation of the file's content, and that there may be other text components after the first `,` (that was probably also the same reason why @Quasimodo added the caveat about greedy/non-greedy regexes). Unfortunately, the OP has not clarified that point very well ...

Comment: @AdminBee sorry, there is no extra info, file is just as shown

Comment: @Woodstock I see, then Inian's solution is "the `awk` alternative" @Quasimodo asked for.

Comment: @Inian I am curious: Why are you setting the `FS` via `-v`; is the `-F` option not portable? I thought only `OFS` needs to be set in this way (as in `-v OFS='='` ...)

Comment: @AdminBee: Yes you are right, POSIX says, they are functionally equivalent. As for why I did that, its just a style I use, no concrete reason behind

Comment: @Inian the second awk can be made more foolproof if the str variable is extracted till the  comma. OTW in the (very unlikely but) scenario of lines like FOO=FOO, will change incorrectly.